# Laravel sin webpack

Tags: laravel, webpack

Creo un nuevo proyecto Laravel en mi ordenador con `laravel new proyecto`. El instalador descarga lo que necesita de internet y crea el proyecto, pero no incluye el archivo `webpack.min.js` para compilaciones de estilos. He probado a instalar npm en el proyecto con `npm install`, pero tampoco aparece. Se crea la carpeta `node_modules`, como era de esperar, pero el archivo `webpack.min.js` sigue sin aparecer. A qué se debe esto? Como resolverlo?

Comment: Desde hace unos días, los nuevos proyectos de Laravel usan Vite para los assets frontend https://mobile.twitter.com/taylorotwell/status/1541795873838989314

Comment: Este es un cambio muy radical, y que descontrola mucho. Por ejemplo, ahora como instalas tailwind en tu proyecto? Con haces que se compilen los assets css y js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En efecto, laravel ahora utiliza vite como compilador, pero en la documentacion te explica como remover vite y utilizar laravel mix.

https://github.com/laravel/vite-plugin/blob/main/UPGRADE.md#migrating-from-vite-to-laravel-mix